# Where can I find a list of timezones in tabular format?

Tags: timezone

I am looking for a table containing a list of timezones, like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1. I need the timezone code (eg. PST, PDT, EST, GMT, UTC), a name (eg. Pacific Standard Time), and the offset from UTC (eg. -7 for PDT).

I've Googled for about ten minutes but have not found this. Does anyone know where can I find this?

Comment: Remember that the "timezone codes" often are ambiguous. For example, "EST" may be UTC+10 or UTC-3 or UTC-5. It's sometimes recommended to use the "Area/Location" format, like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones

Comment: FYI for future peoples' reference...PHP provides native timezone functions: http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php

Comment: **Note to all:**  While lists of these types may be found in various places, using them in an application is never a good idea.  Time zones change, and lists have to be maintained.  Also, calculating using the lists is not trivial, as you have to account for DST transition dates, and historical changes.  Use a platform or library instead, such as Java and PHP's native support, pytz in Python, Noda Time or TimeZoneInfo in .NET, etc.  Do not rely on lists found on the Internet.  Even on Wikipedia.

Comment: Funny that someone is voting to close this when ~20K people have viewed this question.

Comment: If you care for authoritative resources start here: https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you want [List of zoneinfo time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoneinfo_time_zones)?

Comment: Please link directly to canonical and authoritative resources.

Answer (score 8):

How about http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/ ?

Alternatively, from my system:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var tzi in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
{
   sb.AppendFormat("   * {0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5}", 
                   tzi.Id, 
                   tzi.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours, 
                   tzi.StandardName, 
                   tzi.DisplayName, 
                   tzi.DaylightName, 
                   tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
   sb.AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: Warning. The code above list Windows time zones. It is much less accurate and complete as the IANA list. To get the two lists (windows and/or IANA) in .Net you can use the NODA library (available on nuget).

Comment: Please reduce length of answer using `details` or truncate output.

Answer (score 3):

There are no "official" time zone names.  UTC+/-offset is the closest you'll get.  But, in addition to Joseph's answer, [this table of common timezone names and abbreviations](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) might help.  Remember that abbreviations won't be unique (there is more than one EST zone, for example).

Comment: In the US, the boundaries are set at a local level -- county-by-county.  And the Reservations can do as they please with their time zones.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I feel bad for anyone charged with mapping long/lat to TZ.

Answer (score -2):

I couldn't find any good list, so I made one:
http://pastebin.com/Bpc3eNk9

Just execute the MySQL code and you'll have your list in a table names "tz".

Comment: Note that list of time zones are not static. Your list is missing some more recently added zones, e.g. Antarctica/Troll.

Comment: It would be a great answer if there was info about +/- hours with respect to Greenwich